# Bootstrap overrides with less using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem do not take effect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to override variables in my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file, per the instructions in the file. I know the file is parsed because if I introduce a syntax error the application will not load, but setting less variables, e.g.

```
@navbar-default-color: red;
```

does not have any effect. Here is my application.css:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require rails_bootstrap_forms
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 */
```

Excerpt from gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem "bootstrap_form"
```

Here is my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@iconSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
@fontAwesomeEotPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons.less";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and 

@navbar-default-color: red;
@navbar-height: 1000px;
@navbar-default-color: red;
```

In a possibly related issue, I am unable to include glyphicons in my html.

Edit: less variables are interpreted in production when I precompile and push to production (heroku). It appears that it may be an issue with development.

Comment: did you try @navbar-default-color: red !importnat;

Comment: this should not matter, but tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but did you actually look at the compiled css? or you just test it in a browser?

Comment: And one more question, just in case, what Bootstrap version it is?

Comment: This is the latest version of bootstrap and twitter-boostrap-rails 3.2.0. I looked at this in the browser, but have tried removing and recompiling assets. Currently I do not have assets precompiled locally.

Comment: Update: This does work on production when I compile assets and push to heroku. Still doesn't work locally though.

Comment: So it definitely looks like a problem with some paths of your local environment (or so, something like "linked files in your html/css just do not point to the files you compiled"), but I'm absolutely not familiar with this development environment to help though (I even can't understand how it can be "I do not have assets precompiled locally" and "Still doesn't work locally though" simultaneously.). Sorry.

Comment: I believe locally it's looking at the uncompiled assets, which is too inefficient to do in production. If it looked at compiled assets in development, you would either have to recompile between page loads or explicitly after each change, which would be a pain. One fix would be to move to precompiled assets in development, but that would slow iteration. I'm hoping for a better solution. Again, the less file is parsed so the issue is not that it's not in the path. It's just ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with my development.rb file. I was able to fix it by setting the following variable:

```
  config.assets.debug = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Require tree should always come at last in `application.css` file

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require rails_bootstrap_forms
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: Order of requires doesn't matter for this particular issue.